# Pig AvroStorage + Unsupported type in record:class org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I am trying to read csv files as input data and write the output in avro format.

Note :- Pig Version  Apache Pig version 0.12.1.2.1.5.0-695

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar; 
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/piggybank.jar;
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar;
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar;
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar;

 A = LOAD '/data/raw/event'; 

store A into '/data/dev/raw/pig' 

using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage('no_schema_check',
'schema', ' {  
  "name" : "EVENT",
  "type" : "record",  
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "evt",
    "type" : [ "long", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "mac",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "sec",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ]
  } ]

}');
```

I get the below exception :

```
ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AteException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
 Unsupported type in record:class org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray

        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:263)
        at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroRecordWriter.write(PigAvroRecordWriter.java:49)
        at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.putNext(AvroStorage.java:749)


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported type in record:class org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray
        at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.getField(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.writeRecord(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:363)
```

Please let me know If I have missed any thing or if any work around exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Pig will load all the fields as DataByteArray. 
So you have to load the data with schema as follows

```
A = LOAD '/data/raw/event' as (evt:long,mac,int,sec:int)
```